# List all roles a user has, that contain in the name 'Responsible'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a site with many user roles. Right now, when I press the button, all the roles the user has are being displayed. How can I make it to give me only the roles that contain 'Responsible' in their name?

This is what I have in the Controller:

```
ViewBag.RolesForThisUser = Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName);
```

And this is what I have in the View:

```
@if(ViewBag.RolesForThisUser != null) {
    @foreach (string s in ViewBag.RolesForThisUser)
        {
            <li>@s</li>
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an if statement.

```
@if(s.ToLower().Contains('responsible') {
 <li>@s</li>
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.